# XML version 1.1 in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml, unicode, version, for-xml

Is it possible to use XML version 1.1 (not 1.0) within SQL Server?

Basically I need to include some C0 characters (like 0x0001) into xml using the `FOR XML` statement, but I can't since it is not allowed in XML v1.0.

I'm aware that I can use base64 or CDATA encodings but I want to keep my xml data human-readable.

Comment: I just wondered this myself!